# Counting documents by property occurrence in Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, bigdata, kibana

I'm trying to create a visualization that looks like this:

- Foobar, 10
- Bar, 8
- Baz, 5.6

The first column is the aggregation itself. Imagine i have documents like this:

```
{
  id: 1,
  name: 'lorem ipsum',
  type: 'A'
  author: {
    name: 'Foobar',
  }
}
{
  id: 2,
  name: 'dolor sit amet',
  type: 'B',
  author: {
    name: 'Foobar',
  }
}
```

So, i want to add a +1 to the score of "Foobar" everytime i find a document of type A. And a +2 to the score if i find a document of type B. Basically, aggregating by the author name, and calculating a dynamic value on results.

Is this possible in Kibana? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Whoever downvoted, can you please elaborate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK, you can't do this in Kibana in `visualize` panel, maybe you can try it in program then index the result into es.

Comment: What do you mean by program? Outside Kibana?